# Exoplayer; merge ConcatenatingMediaSource with audiotrack?

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I have a list of HLS urls that I need to play consecutively with exoplayer 2. This is not a problem:

```
val mediaSources = arrayOfNulls<MediaSource>(videoModel.Clips.size)
for (i in videoModel.Clips.indices) {
    mediaSources[i] = buildVideoSource(videoModel.Clips.get(i).StreamUrl)
}
val videoSource = if (mediaSources.size == 1) mediaSources[0] else ConcatenatingMediaSource(*mediaSources)
```

The problem here is that I need to mute these videos, and play a mp3 audio track instead as background tune. How should I go about this? I thought I could just use a MergingMediaSource like this:

```
val audioSource = buildAudioSource()
val mergedSource = MergingMediaSource(videoSource, audioSource)
player!!.prepare(videoSource)
```

But that throws the following error: The merge failed because the sources have different period counts.

```
Source error:
com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MergingMediaSource$IllegalMergeException
   at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MergingMediaSource.checkTimelineMerges(MergingMediaSource.java:169)
   at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MergingMediaSource.handleSourceInfoRefreshed(MergingMediaSource.java:144)
   at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MergingMediaSource.access$000(MergingMediaSource.java:34)
   at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MergingMediaSource$1.onSourceInfoRefreshed(MergingMediaSource.java:102)
   at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ConcatenatingMediaSource.handleSourceInfoRefreshed(ConcatenatingMediaSource.java:142)
   at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ConcatenatingMediaSource.access$000(ConcatenatingMediaSource.java:34)
   at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ConcatenatingMediaSource$1.onSourceInfoRefreshed(ConcatenatingMediaSource.java:81)
   at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.HlsMediaSource.onPrimaryPlaylistRefreshed(HlsMediaSource.java:142)
   at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.playlist.HlsPlaylistTracker.onPlaylistUpdated(HlsPlaylistTracker.java:385)
   at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.playlist.HlsPlaylistTracker.access$1200(HlsPlaylistTracker.java:41)
   at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.playlist.HlsPlaylistTracker$MediaPlaylistBundle.processLoadedPlaylist(HlsPlaylistTracker.java:590)
   at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.playlist.HlsPlaylistTracker$MediaPlaylistBundle.onLoadCompleted(HlsPlaylistTracker.java:539)
   at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.playlist.HlsPlaylistTracker$MediaPlaylistBundle.onLoadCompleted(HlsPlaylistTracker.java:472)
   at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.handleMessage(Loader.java:383)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

I have 2 questions:

1. How can I mute incoming HLS stream? I'd preferably not load the audio at all to save data usage.
2. How can I play a seperate audiotrack under a `ConcatenatingMediaSource`?

Comment: Did you try wrapping the AudioSource in a LoopingMediaSource?

Comment: @damian yes, just now. Still throws exactly the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

u can disable audio , in exo player Demo application, you can select audio button and choose disable.
 you can see the demo code to see how  disable the audio

Comment: I understand, but the possibility of using this solution heavily depends on how I play the background MP3. Besides, the audio is still being downloaded this way and this is something I'd like to avoid, if possible.